# Can I see the values set in `ml2_conf.ini` as a regular OpenStack user (non-admin)?

Tags: networking, openstack

My company uses a managed instance of OpenStack. I am **NOT** an administrator on this instance. There is functionality that OpenStack offers behind the `enable-ml2-dns` configuration options, this is set in the [`ml2_conf.ini`](https://docs.openstack.org/newton/config-reference/networking/samples/ml2_conf.ini.html).

> In order to enable internal DNS resolution, the user must set the `enable-ml2-dns` to True. The default value is False in order to provide backwards compatibility with existing deployments.

Is it possible to find out this setting without being an administrator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. The *.ini files are usually only configured by the cloud operators.

Comment: 50 years ago people flew to the moon, so there HAS TO BE A WAY (as Allan Bean would say back then) ...